# Regex start searching from the end of the string (reverse)

Tags: regex

I have strings that have blocks enclosed in underscores in them. Example:

```
*Text* _word_ it is something we read every day. _Words in texts_ can be really expressive. _A nice text is a pleasure for your body and soul_ (Oscar Wilde)
```

In the example above there are three such blocks but the number varies from string to string. I want to match only the last one, i.e. *starting from the end of the line* lazily skip characters until the first _ is found, skip any following characters until encountering the second _ and stop right there.

It is easy to to find a similar block if we were looking for the very first one inside the string, but how about finding the *last* one?

Comment: what output you are expecting?

Comment: I'm expecting a match actually. The text between the second last _ and the end of the string should be matched.

Comment: @ЗахарJoe so `"A nice text is a pleasure for your body and soul"`? be explicit

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Have a try with:

```
((?:_[^_\r\n]*){2})$
```

It matches an underscore followed by any number of any  character that is not underscore or line break, all that occurs twice before the end of lien.

Comment: M, hey, getting somewhere! It works but there's a catch/bug: it matches until the next line with any underscore inside. I.e. if the lines following the intended match are without underscores then the result will expand until the very first line that contains them. But that line won't be included, only the ones preceding it will. Example: 1: this _is_ a line with _matches_ and _stuff_ 2: this is just a simple line 3: another line 4: now _we_ have matches again. The expression will match everything from 1: _stuff until the 3: line

Comment: @ЗахарJoe: See my edit, I've added line break. Is this working?

Comment: M42, working _perfectly_! However it's not the end, I'd really be grateful if you could explain how that was achieved, could be useful to other folks with a similar problem. The expression is quite advanced.

Answer (score 24):

***The text between the second last _ and the end of the string should be matched***

Use a negated character class, like

```
([^.]*$)
```

It will match everything from the end of the string that isn't `.`, resulting in the last quote (assuming each quote ends with a `.`)

http://regex101.com/r/fA3pI7/1

Comment: Well, that doesn't quite work in my case. Sometimes the last _ _ block contains multiple sentences separated by dots. I'm explicitly looking to match the second last _ (underscore)  Also sometimes the string itself ends with a dot.

Comment: Are you using any programming language to process the result, or do you need the answer just using a regular expression?

Comment: I'm using a TextMate text editor to process those lines, so it should be just an expression.

Comment: ʰᵈˑ : your solution was excellent: clean and elegant. Thanks. It may not have worked for the OP but for a reverse search is very useful for many applications. e.g extracting the filename from a full path we can use `"[^/]*$"`