# Using regex and stringr to extract the last portion of a URL

Tags: r, regex, tidyverse, stringr

I'm doing hundreds of URL redirects and need to extract all the text after the last forward slash, so:

`/blog/2018/9/28/my_article1` becomes `/my_article1`

I'd like to use the `stringr` package from `tidyverse` ideally. I saw a similar question (not for R) here:

[Regex start searching from the end of the string (reverse)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26528879/regex-start-searching-from-the-end-of-the-string-reverse)

... and tried this:

```
df %>% 
  mutate(new.page = str_extract(old.page, "/[^\/]+$/"))
```

... but get the error:
`Error: '\/' is an unrecognized escape in character string starting ""/[^\/"`

I tried removing the escaping backslash, but to no avail.

Below is a `dput` reprex data example of the original URLs where `old.page` is what I'm starting with and `new.page` where I'd like to get to.

```
structure(list(old.page = c("/blog/2018/9/28/my_article1", "/blog/2013/05/22/1735", 
                            "/blog/2013/02/27/my-goals", "/blog/2013/01/23/leading-change", 
                            "/blog/2013/11/19/2-blog-posts-in-1"), new.page = c("/my_article1", 
                                                                                "/1735", "/my-goals", "/leading-change", "/2-blog-posts-in-1"
                            )), class = c("spec_tbl_df", "tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, 
                                                                                                       -5L))
```

Comment: `basename()` might be a simple solution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to avoid regex you can use `basename()`. the `paste0()` is the include the backslash in the new column.

```
df %>% 
  mutate(new.page = paste0("/", basename(old.page)))
```

or with regex

```
df %>%
  mutate(new.page = gsub('.*\\/', "/", old.page))
```

Comment: had no idea there was a function as elegant as `basename`. Thanks for posting the regex also.

Answer (score 1):

We can use `str_remove`

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
df %>% 
     mutate(new.page = str_remove(old.page, ".*(?=/)"))
# A tibble: 5 x 2
#  old.page                           new.page          
#  <chr>                              <chr>             
#1 /blog/2018/9/28/my_article1        /my_article1      
#2 /blog/2013/05/22/1735              /1735             
#3 /blog/2013/02/27/my-goals          /my-goals         
#4 /blog/2013/01/23/leading-change    /leading-change   
#5 /blog/2013/11/19/2-blog-posts-in-1 /2-blog-posts-in-1
```

---

With `str_extract`, we extract the `/` followed by characters that are not a `/` until the end (`$`) of the string

```
df %>% 
     mutate(new.page = str_extract(old.page, "/[^/]+$"))
```